How can i run a fake amazon SQS queue locally so that it should run in a specified port without the help of docker
I am trying to test the code that is interacting with the Amazon SQS queue,unfortunately, i am unable to find any relevant Maven dependency to make it done.
I expect a maven dependency that does not use a spring or spring boot.

Can you add some more details what exactly you are trying to run? How you are connecting, what you are connecting to etc. ? Any additional details is appreciated.

Im writing unit testing with the help of Juint , i want to mock Amazon SQS calls, (I want to run fake Amazon SQS locally) without the docker setup, but I am unable to find any relevant dependencies
